# Android Market multiple apks

Tags: android, google-play, apk

Suppose application has multiple apks for different countries. If US user with international roaming traveling to another country say China and searches for app, which apk will he get? The one that is meant for US, because locale on his phone will still be set to US or the one meant for China because he is downloading from China.

Thanks

Comment: my guess is the china version. I imagine the market is basing your locale on the ip your device is currently using. But this is just a guess, I have no specific experience or evidence that leads me to that conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't actually be possible for this to happen.

From http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html

> By publishing your application with multiple APKs, you can:
>
> ```
> Support different OpenGL texture compression formats with each APK.
> Support different screen configurations with each APK.
> Support different platform versions with each APK.
> ```
>
> Currently, these are the only device characteristics that Android
>   Market supports for publishing multiple APKs as the same application.